# Error while uploading hex file in DSPIC33CK32MC102

Tags: pic, programming, code

I am using DSPIC33CK32MC102 SSOP package, I have code and its hex file ready. I made the connections for the controller those are as follows:

1. Pullup resistor of 5.5 kΩ for MCLR pin and 100 Ω between pullup and MCLR pin
2. 0.1 uF ceramic capacitor between VDD and VSS as told in datasheet

I am using PICKIT 4 for programming where the pin are connected as follows:

- MCLR = pin 27
- VDD = pin 20
- VSS = pin 19
- PGD = pin17
- PGC = pin 18

The connections are perfect and no wire is bas solder

When I plug USB to laptop and click "connect" it says following error and connects anyhow:

> Target Device ID (0x0) is an Invalid Device ID.
> Please check your connections to the Target Device.
> UDID1 = 000000
> UDID2 = 000000
> UDID3 = 000000
> UDID4 = 000000
> UDID5 = 000000

After this, when I click "program" it gives following error:

> Programming did not complete.
> You are trying to change protected boot memory. In order to do this you must select the "Boot, Secure and General Segments" option on the debug tool Secure Segment properties page.

Then in settings > secure segment > segments to be programmed > Boot, General and Config segment is selected.

After this, when I click "program" it gives following error:

> [ Pgm ] at 0x0, expected 0x00040200, got 0x00000000.
> You have set the program speed to Normal. The circuit on your board may require you to slow the speed down. Please change the setting in the tool properties to low and try the operation again.
> Programming did not complete.

Then in settings > PICKIT4 tool options > programming speed > low selected.

After this, when I click "program" it gives following error:

> [ Pgm ] at 0x0, expected 0x00040200, got 0x00000000.
> Programming did not complete.

Also this approach:

> Target Device ID (0x0) is an Invalid Device ID. Please check your connections to the Target Device.
> UDID1 = 000000
> UDID2 = 000000
> UDID3 = 000000
> UDID4 = 000000
> UDID5 = 000000

After this I click "erase" followed by "read" it says:

> Read complete
> Warning: Debug bit is set on target image. This may not run correctly in production.

Now if I hit "program" it says following warning:

> Memory Image changed do you wish to continue programming device

Selecting yes it programs successfully, but I don't know what has he program its more like a blank file is been programmed.

The following memory area(s) will be programmed:

> program memory: start address = 0x0, end address = 0x5eff
> configuration memory
> Programming/Verify complete
> 2023-08-02 15:58:58 +0530 - Programming complete
> ***   Hold In Reset mode is enabled   ***

Checking CLKO clock output also gives a constant voltage level.

I am using external 3.3 V supply for VDD. The #pragma DEBUG = OFF/ON whatever it is, its not available in config file for this controller
Also this controller doesn't have VCAP pin. If anyone has experienced it before their response would be appreciated. Also is it a hardware related error, software related?

Answer (score 0):

`Memory Image changed do you wish to continue programming device`

When you did an erase then read, this means that you have read the chip after it has been erased, hence it looks:

`like a blank file is been programmed.`

I would try to reload the HEX file and then try to program again. Something has happened to 'fix' the communication, but I'm not sure what.

And the chip is probably not running because `*** Hold In Reset mode is enabled ***`

For this, you need to find the "Release from reset" setting. This is in Settings menu in the IPE. In the IDE, it's a blue circular arrow button (next to the Read Device Memory button).